# Did any DC hero (in particular Batman) ever learn any alien martial arts?

Tags: dc, batman, martial-arts

In one **Teen Titans** episode, Starfire's sister, Blackfire, is comically shown throwing Robin while teaching him some techniques from a strange alien fighting system. The only alien martial art very heavily mentioned in DC are the Kryptonian fighting arts, which are comparable to Yang style combat *Tai Chi* and Kundalini Yoga. This lead me to wonder....

Is there any canon record or example of DC heroes, in particular Batman, learning any type of extraterrestrial fighting system in-depth?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for Earth super heroes knowing alien martial arts? Because I assume Starfire, Hawkman, etc. would use the martial arts of their home planets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Surprisingly it's not Batman, but Lois Lane, who mastered klurkor, a Kryptonian martial art.

She demonstrates it in *Superman's girlfriend, Lois Lane* #78 (1967) and describes it as "a Kandorian improvement on karate" (Kandor is Krypton's capital city):

[image: Lois Lane kicking butt]

She uses it again in *Superman family* #198 (1979), while roller skating.

[image: Lois Lane does some Kryptonian karate]

Comment: Thank you! That's one. In truth, I'm looking for any outside the Kryptonian Arts. I thought perhaps the Karate Kid would know a few